# nested let and if statements

Tags: if-statement, syntax, sml, let

I am having issues understanding SML's syntax for nested `let`s and `if`s. For example, why is this syntactically ill-formed?

```
fun stuff a =
  let
      val p = 2
  in
      if a = 1
      then
      let 
          val r = p 
      in
          a = r
      end
      else
      0
  end
```

if `a` is 1 then make `a` equal to`r`, if `a` is not 1, then do not create `r` in the first place and return 0. Kinda stupid, but o well...

So, why is this syntactically incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not syntactically incorrect. It is however a type error.

The problem is that both branches of an `if` need to have the same type, whereas your `then`-branch has the type `bool` (`a = b` is a comparison, not an assignment, but if it were an assignment, it'd have type `unit`, which is also the wrong type) and your `else`-branch has type `int`. You can make your code compile by returning a boolean in the else branch like this:

```
fun stuff a =
  let
    val p = 2
  in
    if a = 1
    then
      let 
        val r = p 
      in
        a = r
      end
    else
      false
  end
```

PS: Note that you can only assign to `ref`s in SML, so if you wanted to assign to `a` in your code, you'd need to make it an `int ref` rather than a plain `int`.